# Converting raw sql query to SQL Alchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently executing this query in one process:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.api_key, worker_id) worker_id, c.api_key, a.updated_at, b.user_id, a.country
           FROM TABLE_A a
               INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON (b.id = a.user)
               INNER JOIN TABLE_C c ON (b.owner = c.id)
           WHERE 1=1 
               AND a.platform = 'x'
               AND a.country = 'y'
               AND a.access_token is not NULL
               
                      
           ORDER BY c.api_key, worker_id, a.updated_at desc
```

I'm currently wrapping it using `from SQLAlchemy import text` and then simply executing

```
query_results = db.execute(query).fetchall()
list_dicts = [r._asdict() for r in query_results]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_dicts)
```

and it works, but I would really like to see if it's possible to have it in the other notation, like :

```
db.query(TABLE_A).filter().join()... etc
```

Comment: Have you created SQLAlchemy models to map your tables?

Comment: Yes. You can actually use db.query(TABLE_A).filter()...etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

But the exact way to do it will depend on your SQLAlchmey version and how you've setup your SQLAlchemy project and models.

You may want to check out the [SQLAlchemy ORM querying guide](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_objects.html) and the [Expression Language Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html) to see which one fits better your case.